# Connector/python select after insert

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector, python-3.3

I have a database table with UNIQUE key. If I want to insert some record there are two possible ways. First, the unique item doesn't exist yet, that's OK, just return new id. Second, the item already exists and I need to get the id of this unique record.

The problem is, that anything I try, I get always some exception.

Here's example of the code:

```
def __init__(self, host, user, password, database):
    # set basic attributes
    super().__init__(host, user, password, database)

    #open connection
    try:
        self.__cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
                database=database, user=user, password=password, host = host)

        #self.__cursor = self.__cnx.cursor()

    except ...

def insert_domain(self, domain):

    insertq = "INSERT INTO `sp_domains` (`domain`) VALUES ('{0}')".format(domain)

    cursor = self.__cnx.cursor()

    try:
        cursor.execute(insertq)
        print("unique")

    except (mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError) as err:
            self.__cnx.commit()
            print("duplicate")

            s = "SELECT `domain_id` FROM `sp_domains` WHERE `domain` = '{0}';".format(domain)

            try:
                id = cursor.execute(s).fetchone()[0]

            except AttributeError as err:
                print("Unable to execute the query:", err, file=sys.stderr) 
            except mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError as err:
                print("Query syntax error:", err, file=sys.stderr)
    else:
        self.__cnx.commit()


    cursor.close()
```

but anyting I try, on the first duplicate record I get either 'MySQL Connection not available', 'Unread result'. The code is just example to demonstrate it.

This is my first program using Connector/python, so I don't know all the rules, about fetch the results, commiting queries and so on.

Could anyone help me with this issue, please? Or is there any efficient way to such task ('cause this one seems to be not the best solution to me). Thank you for any advice.

Comment: _Where_ do you get that error? Is it printed as an `AttributeError` or `ProgrammingError`, or raised with a traceback because it's neither of those, or…? Which line does it come from?

Comment: Ok, I've editted the code little bit, so you can see the connection establishing. Method insert_domain() is call in cycle, it crushes at the first appearence of duplicate item. Right now it raises mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available") exception. In previous version it was type error I guess, something like "NoneType has no attribute 'fetchone'. I'm not sure what changes I have made, I'm quite brainstorming right now

Comment: Well, "NoneType has no attribute 'fetchone'" is an obvious problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't fix your code, because you've given us two different versions of the code and two partially-described errors without full information, but I can tell you how to get started.

From a comment:

> In previous version it was type error I guess, something like "NoneType has no attribute 'fetchone'.

Looking at your code, the only place you call `fetchone` is here:

```
id = cursor.execute(s).fetchone()[0]
```

So obviously, `cursor.execute(s)` returned `None`. Why did it return `None`? Well, that's what it's supposed to return, according to [the documentation](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id14).*

What you want to do is:

```
cursor.execute(s)
id = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

… as all of the sample code does.

---

And for future reference, it's a lot easier to debug an error like this if you first note which line it happens on instead of throwing away the traceback, and then breaking that line into pieces and logging the intermediate values. Usually, you'll find one that isn't what you expected, and the problem will be much more obvious at that point, then three steps later on when you get a bizarre exceptions.

---

* Technically, the documentation just says that "Return values are not defined" for `cursor.execute`, so it would be perfectly legal for a DB-API module to return `self` here. Then again, it would also be legal to return some object that erases your hard drive when you call a method on it.

Comment: Oh my god, I was looking for the problem on completely wrong places. It solved everything, Attribute error was caught by try-catch block, so cursor / connection wasn't ready for another query, that's why i got MySQL Connection not available'.

I am very sorry for throwing incomplete, not obvious report, thank you for your help!